# How to get aggregated column within struct select spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I get an aggregated column within struct when selecting?

Below is the input dataset -

```
+--------+------------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|batch_id|batch_run_id      |data_subject_cd|batch_frequency|target_object|Job_Run_Upd_Gmt_Ts|source |column_name           |column_datatype|table_row_count|
+--------+------------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+
|3033    |202101052030043000|employee       |D              |employee     |20210105213443    |source1|employee_id           |bigint         |100            |
|3033    |202101062030043000|employee       |D              |employee     |20210106211003    |source1|employee_name         |varchar        |100            |
|3033    |202101101830043000|employee       |D              |employee     |20210110185509    |source1|employee_department_id|bigint         |100            |
|3033    |202101034670052000|employee       |D              |employee     |20210430445670    |source1|employee_location_id  |bigint         |100            |
|3033    |202101065720891000|employee       |D              |employee     |20210670566381    |source1|employee_finance_id   |bigint         |100            |
|3043    |202101051830043000|department     |D              |department   |20210105185722    |source2|department_id         |bigint         |20             |
|3043    |202101061830053000|department     |D              |department   |20210106185742    |source2|department_name       |varchar        |20             |
|3043    |202103012130263000|location       |D              |location     |20210301223658    |source2|location_id           |bigint         |50             |
|3043    |202101182030083000|location       |D              |location     |20210118213841    |source2|location_name         |varchar        |50             |
|3050    |202102012030083000|finance        |D              |finance      |20210201212358    |source3|finance_id            |bigint         |10             |
|3050    |202102061830283000|finance        |D              |finance      |20210206185615    |source3|finance_name          |varchar        |10             |
+--------+------------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-------+----------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Below is the code I used to create the JSON RDD-

```
query = """
SELECT DISTINCT GeneralInfo ,
                collect_list(struct(TableName, Columns, UsageInfo)) AS TABLES
FROM
  (SELECT (struct(batch_id AS datasetid, '' AS OWNER, batch_frequency AS `RefreshRate`, '' AS ZONE, '' AS Country, max(cast(Job_Run_Upd_Gmt_Ts AS int)) AS LastUpdate, '' AS Description, '' AS BusinessFunction, 'Data Harvesting' AS InfoSource, SOURCE)) AS GeneralInfo ,
          target_object AS TableName ,
          collect_list(struct(COLUMN_NAME, column_datatype)) AS Columns,
          struct(table_row_count AS NumberOfRows) AS UsageInfo
   FROM DATA
   GROUP BY batch_id,
            batch_run_id,
            batch_frequency,
            SOURCE,
            Job_Run_Upd_Gmt_Ts,
            target_object,
            table_row_count)
GROUP BY GeneralInfo
"""

x = spark.sql(query).toJSON()

x.collect()
```

However, for some reason in JSON the LastUpdate column is missing (presuming this is because of the aggregation I did, reason being I want all those target_object for maximum Job_Run_Upd_Gmt_Ts). As part of GeneralInfo column in JSON, LastUpdate should also get appended. Below is the JSON created -

```
{
   "GeneralInfo":{
      "DataSetID":3033,
      "Contacts":"",
      "RefreshRate":"D",
      "Zone":"",
      "Country":"",
      "Description":"",
      "BusinessFunction":"",
      "InfoSource":"Data Harvesting",
      "source":"source1"
   },
   "Tables":[
      {
         "TableName":"employee",
         "Columns":[
            {
               "column_name":"employee_id",
               "column_datatype":"bigint"
            },
            {
               "column_name":"employee_name",
               "column_datatype":"varchar"
            },
            {
               "column_name":"employee_department_id",
               "column_datatype":"bigint"
            },
            {
               "column_name":"employee_location_id",
               "column_datatype":"bigint"
            },
            {
               "column_name":"employee_finance_id",
               "column_datatype":"bigint"
            }
         ],
         "UsageInfo":{
            "NumberOfRows":100
         }
      }
      
    ]
 }
```

Please help me on this, where exactly I'm going wrong (not sure why I'm unable to get the LastUpdate column within this JSON).

Comment: could you please provide input data as text format ? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Steven - Have edited my post, please check.

Comment: @Steven - Did you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting `Job_Run_Upd_Gmt_Ts` to int but data is not in int range you should considering casting it to long.

Since you cast the column to int which is out of int range you will get null and max of null will be null. `to_json` will neglect the nulls from struct.

```
spark.sql("select max(cast('20210105213443' as int)) as out ").show(false)

+----+
|out |
+----+
|null|
+----+

spark.sql("select to_json(struct(max(cast('20210105213443' as int)))) as out").show(false)

+---+
|out|
+---+
|{} |
+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried it with long/bigint as well, but still column LastUpdate is not getting included in the JSON. Not sure why.

Comment: It should work for you. max(cast(Job_Run_Upd_Gmt_Ts AS long)) AS LastUpdate

Comment: Tried this too.

Comment: Not sure what's the issue. But it's working for me.

Comment: Is there any issue with the code I'm currently using ?

Comment: No problem with the query, I just copied as it is and changed from int to long.

Comment: I restarted the cluster, now it is working fine. Not sure what was the issue earlier. Thanks!